# How do I rewrite this recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion, sum, iteration

I wrote a sum of function code iteratively, I just want to redo it recursively. How do I do that? Without an invariant, I am a little lost.

The procedure, when given two integers, low and high, and
a procedure for computing a function f, will compute f(low) + f(low + 1) + f(low +
2)+....+ f(high). For example, ( sumFunc(1, 9, square) == 285 )

```
int sumFunc(int low, int high, int f(int), int end) {
    if ( low == high)
        return f(low) + end;
    else 
        return sumFunc((low + 1), high, f(end + (f(low))));
}

int sum(int low, int high, int f(int)) {
    return sumFunc(low, high, f(int), 0);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is the purpose of this to evaluate `f(int)` at each value from `low` to `high` inclusively, adding the results of each eval together and returning the result ? Its a little hard to tell from what you have posted here.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after. This is the not-so-safe version that mandates the *caller* ensure `low` is no greater than `high` on invoke:

```
int sum(int low, int high, int f(int))
{
    return f(low) + ((low == high) ? 0 : sum(low+1, high, f));
}
```

If it is at-all-possible that `low` is ever *greater* than `high` on invoke, this needs a few safety checks to ensure you don't invoke overflow.

```
int sum(int low, int high, int f(int))
{
    if (low < high)
        return f(low) + sum(low+1, high, f);

    if (high < low)
        return f(high) + sum(high+1, low, f);

    return f(low);
}
```

Comment: @Ganondalf No problem. it should be noted you *can* do this with two invokes of `f()` and squeeze the partition from *both* ends, but I'll leave that for you to consider.

Comment: One technique I like is to have a public front end that does the argument checking, then calls a private worker-bee recursion which doesn't have to do any arg checking.